# GAMS to AMPL OPTIMIZATION

Tags: ampl, gams-math

I wondered if someone could help me make this GAMS model to a AMPL model. I am trying to understand the language.

Before hand thanks! You can see the model below.

GAMS Model

```
set activity / A*G/;

alias (activity,i,j);

set prec(i,j) / 
   A.(B,C),  (B,E).F,  C.D,  D.E,  F.G /;

parameter duration(activity) / A 2, B 3, C 3, D 4, E 8, F 6, G 2 /;

free variable time;

nonnegative variable s(i);

equations ctime(i) 
               ptime(i,j) ;

ctime(i)..  time =g= s(i) + duration(i);

ptime(prec(i,j)).. s(i) + duration(i) =l= s(j);

model schedule /all/;
solve schedule using lp minimizing time;

display time.l, s.l;
```

Comment: Please show how far you got with your AMPL model.

Answer (score 1):

GAMS [convert function](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_CONVERT.html) with the option `Ampl` allows you to generate [AMPL](https://ampl.com/) input file (*.mod) from a [GAMS](https://www.gams.com) model file.